# Как вставить while read в функцию?

Tags: строки, bash, функции, параметры

Пытаюсь написать скрипт, в котором присутствует функция, выводящая файл построчно:

```
linePr (){
while read LINE; do echo $LINE; done < $1
}
```

При этом название или путь к файлу вводятся в первый параметр скрипта.
Однако при запуске появляется следующая ошибка:

```
./program: 6: ./program: cannot open : No such file
```

Файл существует и правильно форматирован.

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Александр, почему Вы приводите здесь код лишь одной функции из всего вашего скрипта? Вы считаете, что ошибка именно в этой функции?

Comment: Добавьте такую команду **первой** в функцию: *pwd; echo $1*. Напишите результат вывода.